# how to zip file download without real file

Tags: java, spring-boot, zip4j

I make zip download.
My code works correctly.

Here is my code.

```
package com.example.controller;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.example.common.CommonException;
import net.lingala.zip4j.ZipFile;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/example")
public class ExampleController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/myDownload", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> myDownload(HttpServletRequest request) throws CommonException {
        
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        ResponseEntity<byte[]> result = null;
        try {
            ClassPathResource myShareDir1CPR = new ClassPathResource("static/share1");
            ClassPathResource myShareDir2CPR = new ClassPathResource("static/share2");
            ClassPathResource myShareDir3CPR = new ClassPathResource("static/share3");
            ClassPathResource myShareDir4CPR = new ClassPathResource("static/share4");

            File share1Dir = myShareDir1CPR.getFile();
            File share2Dir = myShareDir2CPR.getFile();
            File share3Dir = myShareDir3CPR.getFile();
            File share4Dir = myShareDir4CPR.getFile();
            
            ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile("myTempFile.zip");
            
            zipFile.addFolder(share1Dir);
            zipFile.addFolder(share2Dir);
            zipFile.addFolder(share3Dir);
            zipFile.addFolder(share4Dir);

            byte[] binaryData = IOUtils.toByteArray(new FileInputStream(zipFile.getFile()));

            headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=output_file.zip;");
            result = new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(binaryData, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            throw new CommonException(e.getMessage());
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

But I don't want to leave the file on the server.
What I have done is:

```
File createTempFile = File.createTempFile("test", ".zip");
ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(createTempFile);
```

However, an error occurs:

```
Zip file size less than minimum expected zip file size. Probably not a zip file or a corrupted zip file
```

Comment: It is unclear what you wish to achieve here. Please clarify

Comment: This probably answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38455387/exception-when-create-zipfile-in-android-with-zip4j-probably-not-a-zip-file-or